# Meanjs: is the user on a request secure for authorization

Tags: node.js, security, express, meanjs

I used meanjs to generate a project.
There are hasAuthorization functions generated automatically for crud modules. Using the articles example in app/controllers/articles.server.controller.js the authorization is something like:

```
exports.hasAuthorization = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.article.user.id !== req.user.id) {
        return res.status(403).send('User is not authorized');
    }
    next();
};
```

I want to add in user roles so admin or owner can edit like:

```
exports.hasAuthorization = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.article.user.id !== req.user.id) {
        var isAdmin = false;
        for (var userRoleIndex in req.user.roles) {
            if ('admin' === req.user.roles[userRoleIndex]) {
                isAdmin = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isAdmin) {
            return res.status(403).send('User is not authorized');
        }
    }
    next();
};
```

Question 1 is this secure? Or maybe better question is How secure is this?

Question 2 if it is not secure then what is the Meanjs way to make it secure?
Do I have to do something like in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130673/node-js-angular-js-admin-authorized-routes) or is something already built in?

Comment: @AndrewLavers I marked the other question duplicate and added this question which hopefully has difference from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything like in that answer, because (if I remember fine) meanjs is using passportjs for that stuff.

If I may suggest you, you could pass role from route, so you will not have admin role hardcoded, and this method will be more reusable. You can than use it like this:

```
app.route('/articles/:id')
        .get(users.requiresLogin, users.hasAuthorization(['user']), articles.read)
        .delete(users.requiresLogin, users.hasAuthorization(['admin']), articles.delete);
```

Comment: So is using it this way secure? I am doing that stuff since It is either Admin or the creator. I can call the user.hasAuthorization from  my article.hasAuthorization